# Object Oriented Casting issue

Tags: c#, oop, casting

I have a casting issue and I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me see how I can fix this issue?

Basically I'm trying to create a CSV generator console program that will take a list of machine records from the DB and put them into a CSV.

The code below is simplified but generally similar to my implementation currently:

```
public interface IRecord 
{

}

public class MachineRecord : IRecord
{
    string Name {get;set;}
    string ErrorCount {get;set;}
}

public interface IRecordStore
{
    string GenerateRecord(IRecord record);
}

public class CSVMachineRecordStore : IRecordStore
{
    public string GenerateRecord(IRecord record)
    {
        var machineRecord = (MachineRecord)record;
        var strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        strBuilder.Append(machineRecord.Name);
        strBuilder.Append(machineRecord.ErrorCount);
        return strBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

So basically here I've created a class that inherits from IRecordStore, and in our case we have to create an implementation of GenerateRecord. The problem here is I have to cast the record of be of type MachineRecord or the compiler will throw a casting error out, this is due to Record not having any properties set.

Is it possible to not have the direct cast in this implementation so this line of code will be like:

```
public class CSVMachineRecordStore : IRecordStore
{
    public string GenerateRecord(IRecord record)
    {
        var machineRecord = record; //we want to remove the explicit cast
        var strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        strBuilder.Append(machineRecord.Name);
        strBuilder.Append(machineRecord.ErrorCount);
        return strBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

I know I can fix this issue by adding Name and ErrorCount properties to IRecord, but IRecord is a very generic interface that can have anything.

We want to be able to create a CSV program that can handle machine records, customer records, employee records, supplier records, etc...

I'm thinking of using generics, and I've played with them a bit but I've had some trouble getting it to work too.

Comment: If you need to handle an object as a MachineRecord, your input type should be MachineRecord, not IRecord.  If you need it to remain as IRecord, you should probably move the required properties and methods into the interface

Comment: Can IRecord have `string GenerateRecord()`? That way anything that is an IRecord automatically has to implement a way to generate the CSV using its own properties

Comment: I'm wondering where you add the C of the CSV... There could be a generic way using reflection, getting all the properties of the current IRecord implementation, and using a `string.Join` to get them together separated by a separator of your choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use generics:

```
public interface IRecordStore<T> where T:IRecord
{
    string GenerateRecord(T record);
}
```

Then implement:

```
public class CSVMachineRecordStore : IRecordStore<MachineRecord>
{
    public string GenerateRecord(MachineRecord record)
    {
        var machineRecord = record; //we want to remove the explicit cast
        var strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        strBuilder.Append(machineRecord.Name);
        strBuilder.Append(machineRecord.ErrorCount);
        return strBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

I wrote this in a hurry, make sure to check for silly errors.

Comment: Also you must add Public access modifer to Name and ErrorCount Properties

Comment: Good catch @MazaherBazari. They won't show if not properly exposed.

Comment: This is right, but I was hoping to keep all my IRecord there. Darn. I was hoping to have a more generic CSVMachineRecordStore that took abstractions. Trying to follow the Dependency Inversion principle in SOLID. Wouldn't this be tightly coupling my code?

Comment: Well, with IoC your class has no knowledge of the injected object. Your current method implementation expects properties of a particular type (`MachineRecord`) so you are already breaking the IoC principle there. If the two properties in question (`Name` and `ErrorCount`) are shared by all objects, then you can just define them in the `IRecord` interface. That will make them available regardless of the type of object and your code will work without generics.

Comment: If I used the factory method pattern, would it fix this problem? If I create another class that takes care of the creation of string creation in GenerateRecord. I would think it would fix this issue?  For example, I pass GenerateRecord(IRecord record) and then inside the function, do something like CSVRecordFactory.CreateCSVString(record, "MachineRecord");Thank you by the way! Trying to learn to do things the right way.

Comment: I think I see where you are going with this. You could create an `ICsvStringFormatter` interface with a `GenerateRecord` method. You can then inject a concrete implementation (`MachineRecordCsvStringFormatter`) and let it format the record.

Comment: I think that's the best way. Thanks!!!! It would make the system easier to unit test and keeps it more SOLID.

Answer (score 0):

The type casting exception occurs when the `IRecord` instance is not an instance of `MachineRecord`.

To answer your question how to fix the casting issue, you should have a look at the [as operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as).

However, for me this looks like making the `IRecordStore` interface generic could help you prevent the type issues you're experiencing:

[Edit] I noticed since IRecordStore is an interface you could even make the generic type [contravariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-generic-modifier). This allows you to assign a variable 
 of type `IRecordStore<IRecord>` with an instance of `IRecordStore<MachineRecord>` or more explicitly `CSVMachineRecordStore`.

```
public interface IRecordStore<in T> where T : IRecord
{
    string GenerateRecord(T record);
}

public class CSVMachineRecordStore : IRecordStore<MachineRecord>
{
    public string GenerateRecord(MachineRecord record)
    {
        var machineRecord = record;
        var strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        strBuilder.Append(machineRecord.Name);
        strBuilder.Append(machineRecord.ErrorCount);
        return strBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I posted the same answer seven minutes ago. Why post it again?

Comment: Sorry, I was testing some code variances before posting, because I prefer to deliver the best possible answer I can give. Therefore, I didn't see you already answered. I gave you an upvote :)

Comment: Got it. No worries. Thanks!